# PhpStorm complains -- and doesn't -- about magic methods

Tags: php, phpstorm, magic-methods

The code IS working. The question is not about whether one should or should not use magic methods, its advantages vs disadvantages and what not. This question will probably be reviewed by a moderator, saying that it is not a real problem and all, but bear with me.

In the screenshot you can see that I use two different buffers (from the same base class) to decide if or not to store a received file (it's a controller dealing with a POST request).

As it is Saturday night and I have no life at all, I decided to pay attention to the seemingly disparate squiggle lines being shown at only one object while the other object is from the same class. WTF moment for me. So I decided to ask what am I not seeing.

The objects are `$original` (a possibly first occurrence of an import request), and `$register` (the new import request register). Both are Eloquent Models (as seen on the right side of the screenshot).

I did the usual inspections and tinkering in, well, Artisan Tinker, only to confirm that the two objects are from the same class, both respond correctly to the `->property` syntax, and that there's no hidden camera recording a practical joke on me. It must be because I AM the joke, for not being able to understand why PhpStorm complains about magic methods on one object, and not on the other.

I know how to turn off the warning, but that's not the point. The point is:

What is the difference between these two objects, since both are populated with a single record?

I've tried:

1. annotating the class to create `@property`;
2. using the static style syntax - `ImporRegister::create();`
3. doing the rain dance in a desperate attempt there was something wrong with my eyes;

[image]

Comment: Those objects were created differently. One is direct instantiation and another one via query. Check what PhpStorm thinks about both of them (quite likely there will be more than one class for `$original`). Place a caret on each and invoke `View | Quick Documentation` (`Ctrl + Q` here using Windows keymap)

Comment: Hum, I knew I was missing some detail like that. It’s not just about having the same origin, but the journey to maturity matters a lot. 

Thanks for pointing that out, and also for fine tuning my question, especially about the “weather” vs “wether”. I did go back and edit the title the minute I saw I used the wrong auxiliar for the 3rd person, but wasn’t able to spot the thing about product name and code inserts. Why am I mentioning this? Because these little details are, for the most part, responsible for our own slippery.

Comment: What inspection is that exactly? I have some Laravel 6 project, it uses `@property` for ALL fields, and the IDE does not show the underwave for me. Maybe because I have that inspection disabled or fine tuned, or because I'm still on PhpStorm 2023.2 version... At the same time, the IDE clearly uses different color for such properties (Magic Member access). So I would like to double check that.

Comment: The inspection is **Property accessed via magic method**. Anyways, I'm coming to the conclusion that it might be related to some sort of IDE's caching. Also, it could be related to PHP 8.2 deprecating dynamic properties (which are not directly related to how Php Storm inspects code, but is related to some extent).

I'm running PhpStorm 2023.3.1, and I guess I'll go through the @annotation alley, even though I don't like resourcing to extra-language "features" -- but in this case, it's either being productive or being a picky person just out of nothing.

Comment: *"The inspection is Property accessed via magic method"* Can you locate the actual inspection in the settings? I have installed the latest 2023.3.1 and I do not see an inspection with such a name. The error text can be different to the actual inspection name. I see "Dynamic property declaration" one under "Undefined symbols" node. Not sure if it is the one (it wants PHP 8.2 while that project is 7.4 max, even though it currently runs on 8.1).

Comment: In general: there is `"Undefined property"` inspection under the same `"Undefined symbols"` node. It has an option (unchecked by default) to not to report dynamic property where `mixed` / `undefined` etc type is. That's most likely why you do not see it for `$original`. And `@property` basically tells the IDE: "this property exists, do not warn about it". Another bonus using `@property` -- they will be listed in the code completion popup.

Comment: *"Can you locate the actual inspection in the settings?"* Scrap it. I have found it -- it's that "Undefined property" inspection that I have mentioned and expected to be. Just in case/hint: you can access the inspection settings right from the editor via `Alt+Enter` quick fix/intentions menu -- https://i.imgur.com/p1cx5De.png

Comment: That's the one inspection. Hard to find going by the Ctrl+Alt+S (⌘+, in my case). I have to thank you for the unsuspected interest in this question. It made me face the annotation step, resulting in a much better documented code. As I don't have a life, I spent the Sunday doing it - lost case. hahaha. Thanks a bunch.